# Is it okay to use both Bloc and Provider in the same project?

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, provider, state-management

Let's assume that I have some data stored in a database and that I wanna fetch that data when launching my app. I also want that data to be accessible from anywhere on my app because my blocs will depend on it.

So I thought of using Provider to make the data fetched available across all the app and Bloc to handle the state or the events occuring in my app because as of my knowledge, bloc isn't suited to simply put data accessible everywhere like provider.

So my question: Is it okay to use both Provider and Bloc in an app for this specific usecase (Provider won't be used for state management, only for letting data be accedsible anywhere) ?

I'm asking this question because I've seen a lot of people saye that we should limit ourselves to 1 state management package but as I said, here provider is not being user as a state management technique.

Comment: "bloc isn't suited to simply put data accessible everywhere like provider" yes, it is, check https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_bloc#blocprovider

Comment: it reads: "BlocProvider is a Flutter widget which provides a bloc to its children via BlocProvider.of<T>(context). It is used as a dependency injection (DI) widget so that a single instance of a bloc can be provided to multiple widgets within a subtree.

In most cases, BlocProvider should be used to create new blocs which will be made available to the rest of the subtree. In this case, since BlocProvider is responsible for creating the bloc, it will automatically handle closing it."

Comment: That's a good point but I think it ain't my issue really because as I said, my problem is not about bloc being available in all the widget tree but rather if bloc is suited for simply putting data accessible anywhere (when I say data, I don't mean Blocs, but real data. Like a list of Users for example). In bloc you can't declare a method called fetch that fetches data from a database and then make it available in the app. That's my issue that's why I'm using Provider to specifically handle the data fecthing (No state management).

But thanks for the comments mate, really appreciate it <3

Comment: "(when I say data, I don't mean Blocs, but real data. Like a list of Users for example). In bloc you can't declare a method called fetch that fetches data from a database and then make it available in the app." check https://bloclibrary.dev/#/?id=flutter for many flutter samples (for example `Complex List` and/or others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need additional provider to make data available in the app. you just need top level bloc. moreover, if you dive in to the class BlocProvider you will notice that bloc use provider to access it from context:

````
/// Method that allows widgets to access a [Bloc] or [Cubit] instance
  /// as long as their `BuildContext` contains a [BlocProvider] instance.
  ///
  /// If we want to access an instance of `BlocA` which was provided higher up
  /// in the widget tree we can do so via:
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
  /// ```
  static T of<T extends StateStreamableSource<Object?>>(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool listen = false,
  }) {
    try {
      return Provider.of<T>(context, listen: listen);
    } on ProviderNotFoundException catch (e) {
      if (e.valueType != T) rethrow;
      throw FlutterError(
        '''
        BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a $T.
        No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<$T>().

        This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.

        The context used was: $context
        ''',
      );
    }
  }
````

so, you can definitely make a top level bloc that will fetch your data and be available throughout the application.